Android Mockito and JUnit Firebase Auth testing
I'm trying to implement a test in Android using Mockito and JUnit, to Firebase register method (that I did using Dependecy Injection with Hilt)
I received a lot of different erros, and I don't know why. Here's my code:
First for Firebase auth:

RegisterRepository.kt:

package com.example.composetodo.data

interface RegisterRepository {
    suspend fun signUpWithEmailPassword (email: String, password: String)
}


RegisterRepositoryImpl.kt:

package com.example.composetodo.repository

class RegisterRepositoryImpl(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) : RegisterRepository{
    override suspend fun signUpWithEmailPassword(email: String, password: String) {
        Firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
}


AppModule.kt:

package com.example.composetodo.di

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() : FirebaseAuth {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRegister(firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) : RegisterRepository{
        return RegisterRepositoryImpl(firebaseAuth)
    }
}

Now the test file:

RegisterRepositoryImplTest.kt:

package com.example.composetodo.repository

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class RegisterRepositoryImplTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockAuth: FirebaseAuth

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: RegisterRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        repository = RegisterRepositoryImpl(mockAuth)
    }

    @Test
    fun `signUpWithEmailPassword should call createUserWithEmailAndPassword and return Unit`() {
        runBlocking {
            val email = "test@example.com"
            val password = "password_example19038"

            val mockAuthResult = mock(AuthResult::class.java)
            val mockAuth = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
            `when`(mockAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)).thenReturn(Tasks.forResult(mockAuthResult))

            val repository = RegisterRepositoryImpl(mockAuth)
            repository.signUpWithEmailPassword(email, password)

            verify(mockAuth).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        }
    }
}


Error that I get from running the test file:


Executing tasks: [:app:testDebugUnitTest, --tests, com.example.composetodo.repository.RegisterRepositoryImplTest] in project D:\Dev\ComposeToDo
[...]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method myPid in android.os.Process not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
at android.os.Process.myPid(Process.java)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.ProcessUtils.getMyProcessName(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:1)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:283)
at com.google.firebase.auth.AuthKt.getAuth(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:8)
at com.example.composetodo.repository.RegisterRepositoryImpl.signUpWithEmailPassword(RegisterRepositoryImpl.kt:10)
at com.example.composetodo.repository.RegisterRepositoryImplTest$signUpWithEmailPassword should call createUserWithEmailAndPassword and return Unit$1.invokeSuspend(RegisterRepositoryImplTest.kt:41)
[...]
com.example.composetodo.repository.RegisterRepositoryImplTest > signUpWithEmailPassword should call createUserWithEmailAndPassword and return Unit FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException at RegisterRepositoryImplTest.kt:32
1 test completed, 1 failed
Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/Dev/ComposeToDo/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
Try:
Run with --scan to get full insights.
BUILD FAILED in 21s
34 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 30 up-to-date
23:16:46: Execution finished ':app:testDebugUnitTest --tests "com.example.composetodo.repository.RegisterRepositoryImplTest"'.

I tried 2 things, but none of them worked:

Using Roboletric as @RunWith, it ended in two different errors:


The same error:


Method myPid in android.os.Process not mocked


Or it says:


WARNING: No manifest file found at .\AndroidManifest.xml.
Falling back to the Android OS resources only.
To remove this warning, annotate your test class with @Config(manifest=Config.NONE).
No such manifest file: .\AndroidManifest.xml


I saw this piece of code in StackOverflow, I tried, did anything:

(On build.gradle.kts)
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            isIncludeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

In the moment I'm learning about Unit Tests, so any solution will help me so much!!
